# regular expression to match start character of string + space then digits like currency

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I test a string that contains a character at the start then a space and whatever comes after that which could be an integer or float?

Example:

'$ 15'

'$ 15.95'

Comment: What have you tried? it's faster process if you have something...

Answer (score 0):

`/\$\s[\d]*\.[\d]{2}|\$\s[\d]*[^.]/gm`

```
$space(endless digits until)period and exactly-2digits
|OR
$space(endless digits-no periods)
```

```js
const rgx = /\$\s[\d]*\.[\d]{2}|\$\s[\d]*[^.]/gm;

const str = `\$ 15.95 \$ 5 \$ 2.00
\$ 6.90 \$ 1101`;

let matches = [...str.matchAll(rgx)].flat();

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could help you: `^\$ [+-]?[0-9]{1,}(\.[0-9]{1,}){0,1}`, you can test it here: https://regex101.com/

- `^\$`: start with a character
- then add a space
- `[+-]?` then add optional signs
- `[0-9]{1,}` then add at less one digit
- `(\.[0-9]{1,}){0,1}` then add a dot and at less one digit

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regular expression :

. \d+(?:.\d+)?

Test it here : https://regex101.com/r/1oqIO8/1